# How can I create one marker by react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

We can create multi markers by [DefaultMarkers](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DefaultMarkers.js), But I need just one marker. I need to delete before marker and create new marker. How can I do that?

I think other examples are not closer than this to my idea, So let me know if you have better idea.

```
let id = 0;


  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      markers: [],
    }
  }


onMapPress(e) {
    this.setState({
      markers: [
        ...this.state.markers,
        {
          coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
          key: id++,
        },
      ],
    });
  }


  <MapView
     style={styles.map}
     initialRegion={{
        latitude: 28.95761453,
        longitude: 50.83710976,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0200,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0200,
     }}
     provider={this.props.provider}
     onPress={(e) => this.onMapPress(e)}>

              {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                <Marker
                  key={marker.key}
                  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                />
              ))}

   </MapView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove  **...this.state.markers** a line from the **onMapPress** method and check the output. Let me know if there is any error.

```
onMapPress(e) {
    this.setState({
      markers: [ 
        {
          coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
          key: id++,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank You. Now How can I print latest latitude and longitude on consol.log?

Comment: First, try to print console.log(Json.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate)), coordinate object may contain latitude and longitude. if it contains, then try to console.log(Json.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude)) and console.log(Json.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate.longitude))

Comment: try with capital JSON. console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.markers[0].coordinate.latitude))

Comment: Great..! @Alireza

Comment: Another problem.. I have a button and a function. In the function I use this code to show latitude in console. Now When I press the button, in console not happening but for second press I can see latitude in console. Can You help me for this?